# I'm getting error "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 4 column 19 (char 64)" while trying to run my code, anyone please?

Tags: json

Json data:

```json
{
"title": "Iska", 
"number_of_pages": 3000, 
"publish_date": 22/12/23, 
"quantity": 20
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JSON parse error - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 4 column 19 (char 64)"

not parse this value  **22/12/23** to any type

It's inside quotation marks to identify it as **String**.

Answer (score 0):

Your publish date should probably be in quotes as the slashes are likely short circuiting your json.